# Compute flat index using Numba

Tags: python, numba

I need to have a Numba-compatible generic function that takes multi-dimensional indices and the shape of the multi-dimensional array as input and return the flat index.

**Sample Requirement:**

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def flat_index(indices, shape):
    """
    Computes the flat index given multidimensional indices and the shape of the array.
    
    Parameters:
        indices (array-like): The multidimensional indices.
        shape (array-like): The shape of the array.
        
    Returns:
        int: The flat index.
    """
    flat_idx = 0
    
    #--->do the computations here
    # flat_idx should be computed to 37


    return flat_idx

# Example usage with 3 dimensions only:
indices = (2, 2, 1)  # Example multidimensional indices
shape = (5, 5, 2)    # Example shape of the array

flat_idx = flat_index(indices, shape)
print("Flat index:", flat_idx)
```

**NOTE:** In the code above, for simplicity, I have used a 3D array index `(2, 2, 1)` but the function should be able to deal with any dimensions.

Comment: *"the function should be able to deal with any dimensions"* This is not possible in Numba since the dimension is stored as a tuple and not a list so the types are different. There is no template-like feature in Numba though function generator sometimes help (but AFAIK not here). Even if it would be possible, it would be inefficient for array with a big number of dimensions (e.g. >=6).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I expect the number of dimensions to be less than 6 (more likely 2-4 dimensions). The dimensions will remain fixed during run time and will be set through a config file. Could there be a solution?

Comment: Here, you can certainly converts the tuple to a list before calling the function and solve the problem that way but note that this is generally an inefficient solution. Alternatively, you can write the 6 function variants and then call the good one with a Numba Jit generator.

Comment: Related issues: [Index an array with an array in numba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71977824), [Numba compiled function cannot iterate over tuple of numpy arrays with different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71364991), [Numba Creating a tuple from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579283)

Comment: @JérômeRichard: "Alternatively, you can write the 6 function variants", you mean to write 6 functions for different dimensions?

Comment: Yes. I think this is the only efficient solution since it will generate specialized instructions (especially if inlined which is critical here) and there is no need for template-like code anymore though this is cumbersome to write.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: The computation of flat-index is a requirement within another Numba function. So, picking up a correct flat-index generator function based on the num-dimensions during runtime could cause a problem?

Comment: Generally yes, any dynamic analysis of the dimension for indices is expensive. The result is typically a loop with a carried dependency with is inefficient compared to a sequence of few `imul`+`add` instructions (most instructions can be removed in basic loops). In fact, with the later, if the values are known at compile time, then the compiler can even replace the `imul` with shifts or remove the `imul` if the stride is 1 (which is critical for the last dimension if it is contiguous as it enable the code to be vectorized). Jit generator functions help to pay this overhead only at compile time

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Is there a possibility to have something like a `function pointer` which points to the function that needs to be used to compute flat-index based on the number of dimensions? In that case, I will compute the function-pointer before calling the Numba function and pass the function-pointer to it.

Comment: You can certainly do that but this will be very inefficient in a critical loop because such function call cannot be inlined. This reduce the need for a set of conditionals but the indirection + function call will be certainly significantly more expensive than the set of condition because modern processor can predict the conditionals and the dimension of the array certainly do not change randomly (so it is predictable and thus conditionals are quite cheap in comparison but still significantly more expensive than an inlined indexing function).

Comment: Not to mention the function will not have the same input types so it is not easy to store them in an homogeneous container like a list (tuples can but indexing by a variable is not possible AFAIK due to heterogeneous types). This certainly requires an additional level of indirection (i.e. even more expensive) or a jump table on a tuple. If you use the function in a critical/hot loop, all of this is a no-go regarding performance (and a bit complex IMHO too). The jit generator function seems the way to go but one need to test to see if it works well in your case.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Sorry, didn't get why the function would not have same input type? Or do you mean, the function would not have same dimensions for the input?

Comment: The input type would be a tuple of 2 integers for a 2D arrays, a tuple of 3 integers for a 3D arrays, etc. This is different incompatible types in Numba (as opposed to Python, see the above links). With lists there is no issue anymore though but here you have tuples in your example. Functions having different parameter types have incompatibles types.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Ahh I see. It was just a sample code to show my requirements. If lists can work, I can pass the inputs as list or array or whatever.

Comment: I apologize if this is a stupid question, but could you please explain in more detail about the calculation you are looking for? If the expected number in your example is 37, I believe it means that the index is in a transposed order where the first dimensions are contiguous, rather than in the common order where the last dimensions are contiguous. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ken: The first value `2` represents the row-index, the second value `2` represents the column-index,  and the third value `1` represents the frame index in the example below. So, the flat index = (1*5*5) + (2*5) + 2 = 37.

Comment: Can't tell which 2 is which. Is index `(3, 2, 1)` of the same shape 38? or 42?

Comment: I just checked : for the dynamic inefficient version, you can use a typed list conversion (in the Numba function) since Numba already seems to use a kind of jit generator for that. Once converted to a list, you can easily iterate over them in a loop. In fact, you could provide a specialized implementation for example for 1D, 2D, 3D (and possibly 4D) arrays so for the generated code to be generic while being efficient in common cases

Comment: @ken: For index (3, 2, 1), the result should be `42`

Comment: So, the flat index increments initially in the column direction (2nd dimension), then in the row direction (1st dimension), and then in the frame direction (3rd dimension). That is, the order is 2 -> 1 -> 3. This sequence doesn't sound like a simple problem. What is the rule behind this? Also, could you update your question to include examples of 2D and 4D arrays?

Comment: @ken: Yes, that was the logic. But I have decided to keep the function simple and keeping the order as 1 -> 2 -> 3. It would be caller responsibility to swap the first two columns.